# How to pass remote server ip as header in haproxy tcp tunnel with accept-proxy enabled?

Tags: haproxy

I need to a variable for haproxy that is the actual remote ip while still using `accept-proxy`, like `http-response set-header Upstream-Server %[req.real_ip]`. `%[src]` does *not* work and sends the client ip from the proxy protocol if `accept-proxy` is active.

I have a setup like this:

1. haproxy load balancers
2. haproxy ddos protection servers
3. nginx proxying to PHP web applications

1 accepts public Internet HTTP/S connections and `mode tcp` forwards them.
2 `accept-proxy` these connections, terminates `ssl crt`, and then applies anti-bot logic.
3 is the final destination and web application.

This is a pretty complicated setup so occasionally there are hiccups in the configuration which are hard to diagnose because of the number of moving parts. I need nginx to know the IPs of 1 and 2 so it can send that to the actual web application for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very obtuse but this works.

`tcp-request` must appear before any http-request to not cause warnings. `tcp-request connection` is the only scope in which `src` is not changed by the `accept-proxy` directive in `bind`. Thus,

```
frontend http-in
        bind :443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/mycert accept-proxy
        option forwardfor

        tcp-request connection set-var(sess.last_server_ip) src
        http-request add-header X-Forwarding-Frontend %[var(sess.last_server_ip)]
```

This will add the header `X-Forwarding-Frontend` with the value of the server that haproxy received the proxy protocol request from. It must be set as a variable this way, because `src` has a different value in every other context when not as an argument for `tcp-request connection`.